# Avoid fxcop error CA1004 in this case

Tags: c#, warnings, fxcop

I have a case where it is returning objects of type T. My code looks like this.

```
public static T GetObjectsFromWebRequest<T>(string urlPath) where T : class
    {
        T modelObjects;
        try
        {

            //SaveServiceDataIntoTextFile(urlPath);
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(urlPath);

            WebResponse ws = request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(ws.GetResponseStream());
            //Get the response of the webrequest into a string
            string response = responseStream.ReadToEnd();

            modelObjects = XMLSerializeDeserialize.ConvertXMLToModel<T>(response);
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return modelObjects;
    }
```

In this case I don't have any option but add a default parameter like

```
public static T GetObjectsFromWebRequest<T>(string urlPath, T a = null) where T : class
```

Is there any other way I can resolve this violation?

Comment: What does CA1006 `DoNotNestGenericTypesInMemberSignatures` got to do with this code?

Comment: Looks like @Laxmi means [CA1004](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182150.aspx)

Comment: in the above case I have not used T as parameter. For resolving this, I have to use dummy parameter T a = null. Yes..it is CA1004

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2967520/331281), you could use an `out` parameter to convey your result:

```
public static void GetObjectsFromWebRequest<T>(string urlPath, out T objects) ...
```